# How to run xCode 3.2.2 project on xCode 3.2.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ios

I have a iPhone project write on xCode 3.2.2 but i want run it on xCode 3.2.3! I try do it but it show me a message "error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphonesimulator3.1.2'

". Anybody can tell me how to run my project on xCode 3.2.3. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lastest iPhone developer SDK, Apple removed the 3.x SDK (and so the 3.x simulator).

You need to run it on the 4.0 simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have spent 2 hour to slove problem last night :( If you have the same problem with me, just do some step to slove it:

1. Select "Project" menu on xCode.
2. Select "Edit Project Settings" submenu.
3. Look at line "Base SDK for All Configurations", select iPhone Simulator 4.0 (May be it look like disable but you can select).
4. Run your project to compile your project.